# Google Cloud Platform web console - Cloud function metrics graphs not showing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Since a few days before Christmas, a cloud function's performance metrics graphs, such as that for execution time, for memory usage, etc. have not been able to render. There were no errors in the browser's developer console (Chrome). Last time when these graphs were needed, it was a few months / weeks ago and they were showing fine. Is there a way to resolve such issues please?

[Cloud Function web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mn5I.png)

Comment: Same issue. Good that you posted it.

Comment: Has this been solved for you yet? I am still experiencing this problem.

Comment: They've been working on it according to updates on their issue tracker. The problem remained for me too. It seems a work in progress.

Comment: I noticed it's working today. Thanks, Google!

Answer (score 0):

You should report this to the GCP support over [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/) rather than posting it on this forum, they have tools to help check the reason why your dashboard may not be rendering properly and help you identify the reason for it.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this. We had only billing support. Otherwise, I wouldn't post it here.

Comment: Where should we file the issue as this seems a Google Cloud Console issue?

Comment: You can open a ticket directly with support in the free tier, otherwise, you can open an issue [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187225&template=0), although it may take longer to get their attention.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same thing in the same time period you describe. I opened up an issue on their Cloud Functions issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147096825

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful (although I can't really vote).